# C++: How do properly validate my for loop using a cin.fail as to require validation each time?

Tags: c++, cin

So, I am writing code to take in 4 scores each from 3 archers. I am doing this with for loops and have to add validation in the form of a cin.fail. So far i am able to have it recognize that the input is incorrect the first time i enter something but if i try and enter something incorrect again it moves on to the next score.

ex. Please enter the first score for archer 1: (anything besides a whole number is entered)

Entry must be numeric!

Please enter the first score for archer 1: (anything besides a whole number is entered)

Please enter the 2nd score for archer 1:

Here is my code any help would be appreciated.

```
for (archernum = 1; archernum <= MAXARCHERS; archernum++)
{
    total = 0;
    for (endnum = 1; endnum <= MAXENDS; endnum++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter score recorded in end " << endnum << " for archer number " << archernum << ": ";
        cin >> score;
        if (cin.fail())
        {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore (1000, '\n');

        cout << "\nThe score must be entered as a number.";
        cout << "\nPlease enter score recorded in end " << endnum << " for archer number " << archernum << ": ";
        cin >> score;
        }
        total += score;
    }
    cout <<"\nThe total score for archer number "<< archernum << " is: " <<  total << "\n\n";
}
average = total / MAXENDS;
cout << "\nThe average score for the archers is: " << average;
cout << endl << endl;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: You need `while` instead of `if`.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thank you so much! I feel like an idiot for not thinking of that.